# Accessing a git server with git or svn commands

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, subgit

Here´s my problem. I manage a git server with gitolite. I want to access this server using git or svn commands, the clients don´t even need to know whether that´s a git or svn server.

When accessing the server from svn I use user authentication (with the files authz, passwd and svnserve, adn then runnig svnserve), and when accessing from git, I use user authentication with public keys (just like gitolite manage this). The server works under RHEL6.

Any Ideas? I´ve read a lot of information about using git-svn, but -according what I've read- the client should use some git-svn command, and I don't want this. I´ve read this thread [Pushing an existing git repository to SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn) , but I still dont know how to push/pull into/from the server, and make other operations.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: As I understand, you want the same thing as that guy, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077164/git-svn-with-subgit-and-apache

Comment: The problem it's pretty similar. But I would like to solve this on a different way:

- I'd preffer using other thing different from subgit, because you have to pay if you want to manage big projects (maybe it'll be my case).

- I'd like to avoid using apache for authenication. With svn it simply works as I explained. With git it's not so easy, that's why I decided to use Gitolite. But maybe I'll have problems with gitolite when integrating with svn. Could you recommend me some link to learn about using apache with git and svn?

Comment: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2010/02/03/branch-per-feature-how-i-manage-subversion-with-git-branches/  I find this solution pretty easy. This guy just merge a svn and a git repo on the same folder. But they are not bare repos, and in the server I need to manage bare repos (at least gitolite does).

Comment: "Maybe it'll be my case" - If your project ends up being large enough to warrant official support, you'll have what most would consider a good problem to have, and a ready-made solution to it, that you know is a good fit for your project and your team.

Answer (score 0):

There is project for serving git repository by svn protocol: https://github.com/bozaro/git-as-svn

Comment: can you put the relevant codes in the answer as the link might change in the future